# Documentation for HA Strimzi Kafka-Bridge?

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

We are thinking about using the Strimzi Kafka-Bridge(https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#proc-creating-kafka-bridge-consumer-bridge)  as HTTP(s) Gateway to an existing Kafka Cluster.

The documentation mentions the creation of consumers using arbitrary names for taking part in a consumer-group. These names can subsequently be used to consume messages, seek or sync offsets,...

The question is: Am I right in assuming the following?
The bridge-consumers seem to be created and maintained just in one Kafka-Bridge instance.
If I want to use more than one bridge because of fault-tolerance-requirements, the name-information about a specific consumer will not be available on the other nodes, since there is no synchronization or common storage between the bridge-nodes.

So if the clients of the kafka-bridge are not sticky, as soon as a it communicates (e.g. because of round-robin handling by a load-balancer) with another node, the consumer-information will not be available and the http(s)-clients must be prepared to reconfigure the consumers on the new communicating node.
The offsets will be lost. Worst case the fetching of messages and syncing their offsets will always happen on different nodes.

Or did I overlook anything?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The state and the Kafka connections are currently not shared in any way between the bridge instances. The general recommendation is that when using consumers, you should run the bridge only with single replica (and if needed deploy different bridge instances for different consumer groups).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
Do you have a link to communication (blog, ticket,...) about that?
How is the question of fault-tolerance handled? (Especially in kubernetes a kafka-bridge-pod could be restarted all the time).

Comment: Keep in mind that the Kafka connection is TCP connection and that will be lost anyway when the pod dies. So any cluster might better handle and redirect your client, but it cannot HA the Kafka connection it self. So When the pod is restarted, Kube will start a new one and you start from beginning as with any other Kafka client.